# Car Max Range Equation

Tags: energy, kinematics, aerodynamics

In space engineering, thanks to the rocket equation, if you know some properties about a rocket (payload, fuel mass and  specific impulse) you can compute the theoretical maximum distance the rocket can go from earth.

I was wondering if there was a similar equation for cars: given some information about the payload mass, the fuel mass, some other properties of the fuel, and maybe some aerodynamics data, can you compute the theoretical maximum range of a car driving on a road.

We can assume that the car moves at a constant speed on a linear horizontal road, and it drives until it stops because the fuel is exhaused.

Comment: Will you assume the car is going downhill with a following wind?

Comment: I would like to assume the car is on a horizontal road.

Comment: For the rocket the variables are clear... But for a car there are many variables: tire pressure (over, correct or under), correct gear, ambient temperature, wind speed and direction, driver quality (lead right foot syndrome) etc Why not look at the published fuel consumption figures - that’s where I start then because I live in a mountainous area I take the worst figures and it comes out about right...

Comment: I am looking for the theoretical optimal range, not the actual measurement. We can make some assumptions: no wind, no loss of energy due to the tires or the engine, the driver is a robot that drives at constant speed on a linear horizontal road...

Comment: The engine has losses, either theoretical or real...

Answer (score 1):

At a given driving speed car will experience some reactionary force due to combination of multiple components: mainly air resistance and friction in axles and gears. To maintain the desired speed, engine has to overcome this reactionary force by producing equal force.

In a typical combustion engine fuel burns providing thermal energy. Engine then converts thermal energy to mechanical energy and waste heat (ratio depends on coefficient of efficiency; typically below 40%). Mechanical energy will be equal to the mechanical work which could also be obtained by integrating the necessary force over the distance (in this case as velocity is constant, we can assume that the force is constant as well, thus **work equals force times distance**).

If you can somehow calculate (or estimate) total necessary force to maintain the given speed and the total producible mechanical work by the engine (specific heat of combustion and coefficient of efficiency are usually constants), you can then calculate the maximum distance by **dividing work by force**.

Note: This approach ignores acceleration at the start and end (such as when fuel has ran out but the car keeps rolling) of the motion. We can assume those parts to be negligible if the total distance is much greater than that needed to reach the desired  speed.